# QGIS raster calculator - crash minidump

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, slope

I'm new to QGIS and using version 2.10.1-Pisa.

I have two raster layers created from ASTER DEM data. I have one for slope and want to create a binary layer where only pixels between 8 and 60 degrees are included. I've tried "Nepal_Mosaic_Slope@1" >=8 and "Nepal_Mosaic_Slope@1" <= 60 but it says crash dumped and closes QGIS?? Is there something stupid I am doing? 
Once I have done this I want to combine the result with a binary raster of elevation which I assume you can do with merge?

Comment: Can you update to 2.12 and check if the problem also exists there. If yes, please open an issue report at https://hub.qgis.org/issues/ and if possible attach the data. Thank you very much.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should probably be a bug report, if the issue can be reproduced.